# How to use Threading.Timer for a loop on a public non-static method on ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, viewstate

I have the following method:

```
//BOLO stands for Be On The Lookout

public void LoadBolos()
{
    List<string> bolos;

    //If not loaded before
    if (ViewState["bolos"] == null)
    {
        List<string> bolos = GetBolos();

        ViewState["bolos"] = bolos;
        ViewState["index"] = 0;
    }

    else
    {
        bolos = (List<string>)ViewState["bolos"];
    }

    int index = ViewState["index"] != null ? (int)ViewState["index"] : 0;

    if (bolos.Count > 0)
    {
        imgBolo.ImageUrl = bolos[index];
        index++;
        index = index >= bolos.Count ? 0 : index;
    }

    ViewState["index"] = index;
}
```

I need to loop this method every 10 seconds, so I can refresh an image on the aspx page. However, I've noticed that some Thread.Timer functions don't allow non-static functions to be used.

If I convert this method to static, I can no longer access private variables that load on page load, nor can I use the Viewstate nor access the image.

So I was wondering which would be the most accurate way to refresh an image on the page every 10 seconds.

Comment: you need to do this in javascript.  every 10 seconds, poll the server for a refreshed image.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried that option first, I guess I'll have to re do the post now focusing on js

Answer (score -2):

You can refresh the page using the html content using 

    Untitled Page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20"  />
```

Comment: For every 10 secs  <head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
     
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"  />

</head>

Comment: this is not good, as it refreshes the entire page.  browsers can ignore this, as well.